# Confirmação de dados Cadastrais E-mail Senha

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, validação

gostaria de saber a melhor maneira para validar E-mail e senha, para verificar se o usuário digitou corretamente a informação. Ex:

> Digite seu e-mail:
>
> Confirme seu e-mail:
>
> Digite sua senha:
>
> Confirme sua senha:

a melhor forma é validar no código HTML mesmo ou no controller? e no caso destas informações, armazenar no banco também o dado confirmado?

Banco:

> Email
>
> ConfirmaEmail
>
> Senha
>
> ConfirmaSenha

Comment: a melhor forma é nos 2, sempre no front-end e no backend..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ASP.NET MVC tem isso pronto em *Model*, replicável automaticamente para *Views*. Exemplo:

## ViewModel

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Confirmar Email")]
    [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "E-mail e confirmação não são os mesmos.")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "{0} deve ter pelo menos {2} caracteres de comprimento.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Senha")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar senha")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Senha e confirmação não são as mesmas.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

## View

```
@model SeuSistema.ViewModels.RegisterBindingModel

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

> e no caso destas informações, armazenar no banco também o dado confirmado?

Não, você nunca armazena confirmações. Por isso a implementação usa *ViewModel*, e não *Model*. Em *Controller*, você vai fazer um tratamento adicional na hora de salvar o usuário.

Comment: Eu consigo colocar o e-mail em uma classe e o Confirmar e-mail em outra classe? Por que no meu projeto, eu tenho uma classe Funcionario que Herda pessoa, onde o Funcionário precisaria de um Login e Senha, porém outros tipos que herdam a pessoa apenas um e-mail pra contato

Comment: Então, não precisa nada disso. Você coloca a criação toda usando um *ViewModel* e cria o *Model* a partir dele.